# Replace a Date or Time section in a DateTime object in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime object which may or may not already contain some date/time information. With that I need to replace the time with my new time independently of the date and vice versa. How would I achieve this? I can't see anything obvious other than creating two new DateTime objects, one with the old/new date and one with the old/new time and concatenating. There surely must be a better way than this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would write two or three extension methods:

```
public static DateTime WithTime(this DateTime date, TimeSpan time)
{
    return date.Date + time;
}

public static DateTime WithDate(this DateTime original, DateTime newDate)
{
    return newDate.WithTime(original);
}

public static DateTime WithTime(this DateTime original, DateTime newTime)
{
    return original.Date + newTime.TimeOfDay;
}
```

(You really don't need both of the second methods, but occasionally it might be simpler if you're chaining together a lot of calls.)

Note that you aren't creating any *objects* in terms of items on the heap, as `DateTime` is a struct.

Answer (score 12):

DateTime is an immutable structure.

The only option is to construct a new DateTime struct based off your two existing values.  This is the best approach.  Luckily, it's a one liner:

```
DateTime CreateNewDateTime(DateTime date, DateTime time)
{
     return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip the time from an existing datetime by writing .Date

```
DateTime new = oldDate.Date;
```

Add your TIme by either adding the hours, minutes & seconds individually

```
DateTime new = oldDate.Date.AddHours(14).AddMinutes(12).AddSeconds(33);
```

or all at once

```
DateTime new = oldDate.Date.AddSeconds(51153);
```

or by adding a TimeSpan()

```
DateTime new = oldDate.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(14,12,33));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be **exactly** what you're looking for, but the DateTime class has a series of Add methods (AddMinutes(), AddDays(), etc.). I say this might not be what you're looking for, because these return a DateTime, so you would have to do something like

```
myDate = myDate.AddMinutes(60);
```